# checking for time "ago" in Jodatime or java.util.Date

Tags: java, android, datetime, jodatime

I want to display how long ago something happened. For example

- 24 minutes ago //discard seconds
- 3 hours ago //discard minutes
- 5 days ago // discard hours
- 3 weeks ago // discard days

All I have is a `long timestamp` and so I am free to use `java.util.Date` or `jodatime` or whatever other `Time` android uses. I am having such a hard time getting it right. I try to use jodatime with `minus` but I can't quite get the right answer yet.

One approach is for me to do the whole thing myself: first subtract my timestamp from now and then do some arithmetics. But I would rather avoid that route if possible.

Comment: There's a PrettyTime API, have a quick google search

Answer (score 2):

Android provides the utility class `DateUtils` for all such requirements. If I've understood your requirement correctly, you need to use the [DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeTimeSpanString(long,%20long,%20long)) utility method.

From the docs for

***CharSequence getRelativeTimeSpanString (long time, long now, long minResolution)***

> Returns a string describing 'time' as a time relative to 'now'. Time spans in the past are formatted like "42 minutes ago". Time spans in the future are formatted like "In 42 minutes".

You'll be passing your `timestamp` as `time` and `System.currentTimeMillis()` as `now`. The `minResolution` specifies the minimum timespan to report.

> For example, a time 3 seconds in the past will be reported as "0 minutes ago" if this is set to MINUTE_IN_MILLIS. Pass one of 0, MINUTE_IN_MILLIS, HOUR_IN_MILLIS, DAY_IN_MILLIS, WEEK_IN_MILLIS

Comment: I think this is the answer I seek. Unfortunately another bug is preventing me from being able to verify the answer right now.

Comment: It's okay; take your time mate. I'm here in case you need any further help with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
   public class TimeAgo {
    public static final List<Long> times = Arrays.asList(
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(365),
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(30),
            TimeUnit.DAYS.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1),
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1) );
    public static final List<String> timesString = Arrays.asList("year","month","day","hour","minute","second");

    public static String toDuration(long duration) {

        StringBuffer res = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0;i< Lists.times.size(); i++) {
            Long current = Lists.times.get(i);
            long temp = duration/current;
            if(temp>0) {
                res.append(temp).append(" ").append( Lists.timesString.get(i) ).append(temp > 1 ? "s" : "").append(" ago");
                break;
            }
        }
        if("".equals(res.toString()))
            return "0 second ago";
        else
            return res.toString();
    }
}
```

Just call the `toDuration()` method with your long timestamp as parameter.

You can also use `DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString()` . You can read the documentation here [Date Utils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateUtils.html#getRelativeDateTimeString(android.content.Context,%20long,%20long,%20long,%20int))

Comment: There isn't exactly 365 days in a year or exactly 30 days in a month

Comment: that won't make any big difference. anyways the OP is showing approximate time "ago". So that won't make much a difference. Btw you can always use DateUtils#getRelativeTimeSpanString()

Comment: It depends on how you're using the algorithm, the more time that pasts, the worst it will get, given that there are better mechanisms readily available, all it does is propagates a bad idea - I'm very particular about date/time calculations ;)